# How to specify type constraint and inheritance on declaring class?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, interface, type-constraints

I've got an `abstract` class which has a type constraint. But i also want to make the `abstract` class implement an interface.

E.g:

```
public abstract class PostEvent<TPost> : IDomainEvent, where TPost : Post, new()
```

Which doesn't compile.

I don't want this:

```
public abstract class PostEvent<TPost> where TPost : Post, IDomainEvent, new()
```

Because that means `TPost : IDomainEvent`

I want `PostEvent : IDomainEvent`

What's the syntax?

Comment: I do not have a set-up to test it at the moment, but you could try removing comma between `IDomainEvent` and `where`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public abstract class PostEvent<TPost> : IDomainEvent where TPost : Post, new()
```

You don't want a comma between the interface list and the generic constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually implement it (you can't leave the implementation *purely* to the concrete types - it needs to know where to start):

```
public abstract class PostEvent<TPost> : IDomainEvent
    where TPost : Post, new()
{
    public abstract void SomeInterfaceMethod();
}
```

You could also use an explicit interface implementation and protected abstract method if you don't want Otis on the public API:

```
public abstract class PostEvent<TPost> : IDomainEvent
    where TPost : Post, new()
{
    protected abstract void SomeInterfaceMethod();
    void IDomainEvent.SomeInterfaceMethod() {
        SomeInterfaceMethod(); // proxy to the protected abstract version
    }
}
```